# Find Parent Block properties from child block in episerver

Tags: episerver

Is there a way in episerver to find a block hierarchy.
The structure that I have is
Carousal Block includes ContentArea property for Carousal Items
Carousal Item1
string
iselection factory
Carousal Item2
string
iselection factory
In Carousal Item 1,I have a selection factory .I need to fetch **Carousal Block** properties within this selection factory.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no, there isn't a way since blocks doesn't inherit structure that way. They can be used anywhere. Thus if you ask for the parent of a block it will always return the `SysContentAssetFolder`.

To solve your problem (I'm certain there are other ways as well) I'd go for a usage approach. E.g. where is the block used and find the owner, block instances will refer to parents as owners since it is an instance that can have multiple parents/owners.

Now that we know that here's some code

```cs
public class ImageBlockController : BlockController<ImageBlock>
{
    private readonly IContentRepository contentRepository;
    private readonly IContentTypeRepository contentTypeRepository;

    public ImageBlockController(IContentRepository contentRepository, IContentTypeRepository contentTypeRepository)
    {
        this.contentRepository = contentRepository;
        this.contentTypeRepository = contentTypeRepository;
    }

    public override ActionResult Index(ImageBlock currentBlock)
    {
        var blockContent = (IContent)currentBlock;

        // Get block references
        var usageReferences = contentRepository.GetReferencesToContent(blockContent.ContentLink, false);

        if(usageReferences.Count() == 1)
        {
            // easy peasy, only one usage
            var owner = contentRepository.Get<IContent>(usageReferences.First().OwnerID);

            // example
            var ownerType = contentTypeRepository.Load(owner.ContentTypeID);
            if (ownerType.ModelType == typeof(ImageBlock))
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // handle if the block is used at multiple locations
            // ...
        }

        return PartialView(currentBlock);
    }
}
```

The trick in this example is to get all references `contentRepository.GetReferencesToContent` to the loaded block, if we are satisfied with the result do something and move on. In the case you have multiple `usageReferences` you may have to search the loaded page for the correct owner block. In that case load the `IPageRouterHelper`, fetch the current page using something like `var parentPage = contentRepository.Get<IContent>(pageRouteHelper.Page.ContentLink);` and match the `usageReferences` to the items in the contentarea.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric. I have used GetReferencesToContent which works fine but it wont when there is no references. For Instance,I am creating a new Carousal Item which technically is not yet published yet. In this case, I need to first publish the item first  & only then we can use it GetReferencesToContent .its kind of on the go scenario.

Comment: @user15532895 Sure, that would be a limitation but you'll have to live with that. May I wonder why you don't implement the selection factory (an enumeration of) directly on the Carousal Block skipping the Carousal Items?

Comment: I understand its a weird one but Its like base locations list in parent block & selected items of an individual from locations within child block.

Comment: @user15532895 Sure, I got that but the strategy in that case would have to be top down and not bottom up. Find the structure you need from the ContentAreas instead.